# How to automatically reload Node.js project when using pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pm2

I am currently programming Node.js with Express.js, and every time I change a line of code in the file router or app, I need to type the command:

```
pm2 reload id_project.
```

How do I make pm2 auto-reload the project when a file is changed?

Comment: pm2 is a tool used in production mode. Have a look at http://nodemon.io/ , it does exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, pm2 doesn’t automatically refresh our server every time we change files.
You need to start your pm2 project with the --watch cli argument in order to tell pm2 to refresh when files have changed:

```
pm2 start id_project --watch
```

check out [the docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/) for more details, or @rogier-spieker answer which is more detailed.

Comment: ok, so... my server.js uses `#!/usr/local/bin/nodemon" yet pm2 doesn't seem to invoke nodemon

Comment: sorry, @Michael. like I said, I don't actually use `pm2` so I can't help any further than I already did. I just said what I said since it sounds like it will solve the OP's problem. Try looking at other answers in this thread. maybe they can help you out.

Comment: Personally, it looks like the other answer in this thread should get the accepted answer. I can't even delete this answer as long as it is the accepted answer.

Comment: @Thatkookooguy I don't want to downvote, I think Mr.Dung should change the accepted answer...  although I don't expect he will, as almost 6 years have passed

Answer (score 114):

You need to start your `pm2` project with the `--watch` option:

```
pm2 start <script|name|id> --watch
```

Where `<script|name|id>` refers to:

- `script` the path to [the script](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/#auto-restart-apps-on-file-change) you want to let pm2 handle
- `name` the name of the configuration in the ["ecosystem" file](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#cli)
- `id` refers to an already running application using pm2, which can be obtained using [`pm2 list`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#list-managed-applications) (note that this would actually require a `restart` instead of `start`, so it's probably the least desirable of the options)

You could also specify which files/directories to ignore:

```
pm2 start <script> --watch --ignore-watch "node_modules"
```

[Watch & Restart](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/)

Or create an "ecosystem" json file describing how you want `pm2` to treat your project:

```
{
  "name": "project_name",
  "script": "index.js",
  "watch": true,
  "ignore_watch": ["node_modules"]
}
```

[JSON options](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#attributes-available)

Comment: What is the id_project in here `pm2 start id_project --watch`?

Comment: @testteam I've update the answer to update the links and provide some more clarity

Comment: This does not `reload` the app, it `restart`s it

Comment: does `watch` increases more memory resource?

Answer (score 7):

> PM2 comes with a handy [development tool](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-development/) that allow you to start an application and restart it on file change:

```
# Start your application in development mode
# it print the logs and restart on file change too

# Two way of running your application :
pm2-dev start my-app.js

# or

pm2-dev my-app.js
```

Answer (score 4):

pm2 is a Node process manager that has lots of bells and whistles. you can run the below command to automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected.

```
pm2 start index.js --watch
```

Note that because pm2 runs things in the background, you can’t just `ctrl+c` your way out of a running pm2 process. You have to stop it by passing the ID or the name.

```
pm2 stop 0
pm2 stop index
```

other two options are below

```
npx supervisor index.js
nodemon index.js
```