# pm2 --ignore-watch not working

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have been using pm2 for some time now. Recently, I needed to add a custom log directory to my Express4 project called "actionLog". Since it is a directory that gets updated with log files and I don't want pm2 to restart the app on log file changes, I wanted pm2 to ignore watching that directory. After updating pm2 to latest, here is the command I used:

```
pm2 start app.js --watch --ignore-watch="actionLog"
```

I get the following error streaming through the pm2 logs:

```
PM2 Error: watch ENOSPC
PM2     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
PM2     at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1172:11)
PM2     at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1198:11)
PM2     at createFsWatchInstance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
PM2     at setFsWatchListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
PM2     at EventEmitter.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
PM2     at EventEmitter.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
PM2     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:468:21)
PM2     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
PM2 Error: watch ENOSPC
PM2     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
PM2     at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1172:11)
PM2     at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1198:11)
PM2     at createFsWatchInstance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
PM2     at setFsWatchListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
PM2     at EventEmitter.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
PM2     at EventEmitter.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:255:21)
PM2     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:468:21)
PM2     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
PM2 Error: watch ENOSPC
```

I have also tried using the command:

```
pm2 start bin/www --watch --ignore-watch="actionLog"
```

This also generated the same error.

Once I have the correct ignore-watch parameter, I will update the json config file I use for starting pm2. At the moment, using this config file with the ignore-watch is also causing errors, but instead of a detailed stack trace as above, I only see the following in the pm2 logs:

```
PM2: 2016-02-23 04:05:34: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:aadm id:2
PM2: 2016-02-23 04:05:34: App name:aadm id:2 online
PM2: 2016-02-23 04:05:35: Change detected on path actionLog/userAction.log for app aadm - restarting
PM2: 2016-02-23 04:05:35: Stopping app:aadm id:2
PM2: 2016-02-23 04:05:35: App name:aadm id:2 exited with code SIGTERM
PM2: 2016-02-23 04:05:35: Process with pid 5102 killed
PM2: 2016-02-23 04:05:35: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:aadm id:2
PM2: 2016-02-23 04:05:35: App name:aadm id:2 online
```

I have looked at some of the reports of ignore-watch problems such as:

- https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1288
- https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/918
- https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1275
- [How to auto reload project nodejs use pm2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766723/how-to-auto-reload-project-nodejs-use-pm2)
- [Express 4 + pm2 watch not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882759/express-4-pm2-watch-not-working/27893721#27893721)

Unfortunately, I am still stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out even though the errors were triggered by ignore-watch, they were not caused by it. The following command fixed the issue:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

I found this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32600959/2234029

I also tried "npm dedupe" -as suggested on that thread- which didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. **Increase the systems inotify max watch limit:**
   `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

or

2. **Try to decrease you watch count by additionally ignoring `node_modules`:**
   `pm2 start bin/www --watch --ignore-watch="actionLog node_modules"`

If you don't have sudo rights option 2 is for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It was driving me crazy, then I discovered there were many sessions of PM2 running in my system.
A command like `ps aux | grep pm2` shows you all instances running.

So I killed manually each instance (shown by the command above) one by one with:

`kill -9 <pid1> <pid2> <pid3> <...>`

At last I restarted the process:

`pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`

and then everything went working smoothly as written in my config file (without any "watch" option).

The actual question is: why those processes where running on my server, but I can't answer this.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is `ignore_watch`  ie with an underline

Comment: The command line parameter is --ignore-watch. Please see: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/ . If you use it in the config file, then ignore_watch is used. For that, please see: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/

Comment: This command attribute does not exisits